# Diagnosing Visual C++ linker

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

Is there a way to diagnose what is causing linker problems?

I've always had issues with linking my project with Wt (webtoolkit.eu) projects. In the beginning when my project was small, the linker worked on its default settings.

However, when my project started to get bigger, the linker would run for hours, but the process wouldn't complete or report any error. I came around the issue by disabling incremental linker, after which the linker worked perfectly.

Now, I've divided my project into 3 CMake projects (aka targets). 2 are static libraries, while the 3rd is an executable target. These 3 projects additionally link with Wt projects statically. However the linker process never completes or reports any errors on both, incremental and non-incremental setting.

**Additional Informaton:**

Links successfully on Release mode

Using /bigobj as the compiler gives an error without it

**Linker command line copied from executable project Properties->Linker->Command Line**

Release Mode (links successfully)

```
/OUT:"D:\Programming\WebWidgets\build\src\WWTestApp\Release\WWTestApp.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"D:/Programming/WebWidgets/build/src/WWTestApp/Release/WWTestApp.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "..\WebWidgets\Release\WebWidgets.lib" "..\DboInstaller\Release\DboInstaller.lib" "C:\Program Files\WT\lib\wt.lib" "C:\Program Files\WT\lib\wthttp.lib" "C:\Program Files\WT\lib\wtdbo.lib" "C:\Program Files\WT\lib\wtdbosqlite3.lib" "C:\Program Files\WT\lib\wtdbomysql.lib" "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib\libmysql.lib" /IMPLIB:"D:/Programming/WebWidgets/build/src/WWTestApp/Release/WWTestApp.lib" /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"D:\Programming\WebWidgets\build\src\WWTestApp\Release\WWTestApp.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"WWTestApp.dir\Release\WWTestApp.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:/Boost/lib" /LIBPATH:"C:/Boost/lib/Release" /TLBID:1
```

RelWithDebInfo (links successfully)

```
/OUT:"D:\Programming\WebWidgets\build\src\WWTestApp\RelWithDebInfo\WWTestApp.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"D:/Programming/WebWidgets/build/src/WWTestApp/RelWithDebInfo/WWTestApp.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "..\WebWidgets\RelWithDebInfo\WebWidgets.lib" "..\DboInstaller\RelWithDebInfo\DboInstaller.lib" "C:\Program Files\WT\lib\wt.lib" "C:\Program Files\WT\lib\wthttp.lib" "C:\Program Files\WT\lib\wtdbo.lib" "C:\Program Files\WT\lib\wtdbosqlite3.lib" "C:\Program Files\WT\lib\wtdbomysql.lib" "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib\libmysql.lib" /IMPLIB:"D:/Programming/WebWidgets/build/src/WWTestApp/RelWithDebInfo/WWTestApp.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"D:\Programming\WebWidgets\build\src\WWTestApp\RelWithDebInfo\WWTestApp.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"WWTestApp.dir\RelWithDebInfo\WWTestApp.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:/Boost/lib" /LIBPATH:"C:/Boost/lib/RelWithDebInfo" /TLBID:1
```

Debug Mode (does not link)

```
/OUT:"D:\Programming\WebWidgets\build\src\WWTestApp\Debug\WWTestApp.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"D:/Programming/WebWidgets/build/src/WWTestApp/Debug/WWTestApp.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "..\WebWidgets\Debug\WebWidgets.lib" "..\DboInstaller\Debug\DboInstaller.lib" "C:\Program Files\WT\lib\wtd.lib" "C:\Program Files\WT\lib\wthttpd.lib" "C:\Program Files\WT\lib\wtdbod.lib" "C:\Program Files\WT\lib\wtdbosqlite3d.lib" "C:\Program Files\WT\lib\wtdbomysqld.lib" "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib\libmysql.lib" /IMPLIB:"D:/Programming/WebWidgets/build/src/WWTestApp/Debug/WWTestApp.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"D:\Programming\WebWidgets\build\src\WWTestApp\Debug\WWTestApp.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"WWTestApp.dir\Debug\WWTestApp.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:/Boost/lib" /LIBPATH:"C:/Boost/lib/Debug" /TLBID:1
```

Comment: Does you project live on a non-local drive?  Or are your working with a limited space drive?  Both can slow the compile and linking process for VS considerably.

Comment: @AnonMail Hey, no I have enough space and it is on my local drive. And the problem isn't that it is slow... It never finishes

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the linker is somehow running out of memory.

Comment: @AnonMail my system has enough memory, although I'm not quite sure

Comment: Dividing projects into several static libraries would not help whatever linker problems you have since lib is just a container of .obj files, so actual linking of all obj files is still happening in your final project.

Comment: Do you use whole program optimization? What is your linker command-line? What is your linker/compiler version?

Comment: @biocomp I divided it for modularization. Anyway I'm using Visual Studio 2013. And the link.exe shows version 12.00.21005.1. I also had the issue in Visual Studio 2012. And I don't understand what you mean by what is my linker command-line

Comment: I'm not saying modularization is bad, just that it doesn't affect link-times :) When you build, your link.exe will be invoked with a specific command-line, and it'll include all the linker options. W/o knowing those options, it's hard to recommend anything.

Comment: @biocomp Hey I added the command-line parameters in the question. Please take a look :)

Comment: Ok, could you provide linker parameters for release mode (where it links successfully) + also see if linker process is doing anything (spending CPU or how much memory it uses) when it never finishes in debug mode?

Comment: @biocomp Updated the command lines in the question, in debug mode the link.exe process takes about 25% or 30% CPU and about 160mb

Comment: @biocomp is it possible that the contents of the object codes are causing this issue or does the linker simply links the code?

Comment: I don't see anything suspicious in the link commands. It could be the contents of obj files that cause linker to slow down. You did not reply to my other question: " see if linker process is doing anything (spending CPU or how much memory it uses) when it never finishes in debug mode".

Comment: @biocomp I did reply, "in debug mode the link.exe process takes about 25% or 30% CPU and about 160mb memory"

Comment: Oops, sorry, missed that somehow. But is it just constantly doing that? Spending that cpu and memory for a long time, and never finishes?

Comment: @biocomp Yes, sometimes goes down to 20%. Tried VS 2015 today, same problem, more memory usage, 200mb

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by forcing Visual Studio to use the x64 version of the toolchain. Most probably it had something to do with the linker running out of addressable space.